# Проблема с физикой в местах соединения коллайдеров (отскоки на ровной поверхности)

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Есть сцена в 3D с платформами(меши с куб коллайдер), стоят все в ряд одна за одной(образуют сплошную дорогу), по ним катится мяч(сфера с `Rigidbody`), при переходе с одной на другую платформу мяч иногда подпрыгивает.

При старте сцены у `Rigidbody` задается velocity для старта движения, в моменты отскоков на мяч кроме физики ничего не действует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать эти прыжки, почему так происходит?
Пробовал удлинять коллайдеры у платформ, это не помогло, ставил разные `collision detection` у `Rigidbody` мяча - не помогает.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject cam;


    void Start()
    {
        if (!player){
            player = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            player.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
        player.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * 200;

        if (!cam){
            cam = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        }
    }


    void Update()
    {
        cam.transform.position = player.transform.position - (Vector3.forward * 5);
    }


    int roadSectorCount = 0;
    int roadSectorLength = 10;
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        while(player.transform.position.z+100 > roadSectorCount * roadSectorLength) {
            var roadSector = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            roadSector.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, roadSectorCount * roadSectorLength);
            roadSector.transform.localScale = new Vector3(20, 1, roadSectorLength);
            roadSector.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 0);
            roadSectorCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Демонстрация проблемного поведения:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4A1W0eDaXnA

*На данный момент закрыл это созданием невидимой платформы, которая постоянно движется под мячом, следовательно, пересечений с реальными платформами не происходит, но такое решение абсолютно не годится.*

> UPD

Переопределил у платформ методы `OnCollision`.

- Отскок начинается до срабатывания `OnCollisionEnter`(первая фиксирует
  изменения) следующей платформы.
- `OnCollisionExit` предыдущей платформы отрабатывает только спустя
  несколько итераций физики.
- Получается, шар в моменте стоит на 2 коллайдерах одновременно, хотя и
  не должен.

Это поведение наблюдается при всех `collision detection` кроме `continuous speculative` (при нем прыжки будут почти на каждом переходе и может начаться до OnCollisionEnter, причем unity не может корректно обработать возврат на другой детект без перезапуска)

Можно предположить, что мячик частично проскакивает внутрь платформы(при включенной гравитации он иногда проскальзывает немного внутрь), а затем ударяется о вторую, но нет, я отключил гравитацию и мониторил изменение координаты, даже без изменений координаты эти отскоки происходят.

Comment: А как именно у Вас реализовано движение мяча - мы должны угадывать?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Как оно должно быть реализовано?  Если он катиться будет при любой скорости это будет происходить, только сила отскока разная будет.  Если скорость ему начальную через velocity задать, либо через AddForce толкнуть, значения не имеет результат с этими отскоками один и тот-же.

То есть, я его в моменты отскоков сам не толкаю, изначально скорость ему задана и он катится вперед просто.

Comment: То что коллайдер сейчас один это логично, а вариант с уймой плотфор на одной высоте и у каждой свой коллайдер это безтолково и безсмысленно. Коллайдера не должны соответствовать визуалу, они всегда упрощены.

Comment: @Yaroslav, "безтолково и безсмысленно" минусовать вопрос, описывающий конкретную проблему, вместо его решения.
Приведен самый простой пример, в данном случае можно обойтись и одним коллайдером, динамически подгоняя его размер под количество платформ (но это приведет к доп коду).

Но что же делать при более сложной геометрии? Допустим, платформы необходимы разной ширины, тогда что делать? Процедурный меш генерить, чтоб пересечений у коллайдеров не произошло и не было этих скачков?) А если задача еще сложнее будет?)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых убедитесь что реальных зазоров нет, для заметки подскажу тем кто может с этим столкнуться, что можно использовать стыковки обьектов путём зажатия клавиши V и выбрав один из углов и протянуть его к другому необходимому углу.

Также возможно вам поможет решение с Contact Offset у физики, данный глобальный параметр указывает какое значение будет являтся дистанцией касания,  попробуйте установить значение равное 0, или поиграть с значением методом пробы:

[image: скрин]

Во-вторых используйте физическое движение вместо "телепортаций" путём `transform` если в методе Update() указано движение игрока. Вам поможет движение по нормалям поверхности, для удобства есть наглядный видео урок по данной теме: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puPjNRJMmOc (если видео будет доступно к тому времени как Вы это откроете, если нет используйте информацию выше про движение по нормалям поверхности)

(Данный вариант исключает любую возможность падать персонажу внутрь потому что он будет идти строго по поверхности)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вероятнее всего Default Contact Offset является правильным решением проблемы, (а то я уже генераторы коллайдеров писать начал), при нем отскоков заметно меньше, но есть проблема, его НЕЛЬЗЯ в 0 установить, только близким к нулю сделать, поэтому вероятность отскоков все еще есть. Может еще можно что-то подправить, чтобы к абсолютному нулю перейти?

Comment: Касаемо движения по нормалям, проблему с подскоками это не исправит, (ну только если передвижение по оси залочить, как в видео с поворотами сделано) ибо не в проваливании дело, но в целом совет полезен для новичков. Касаемо самого видео, я бы воздержался от продвижения подобных авторов (но это уже придирка).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, к каким выводам я пришел. По всей видимости, решить данную проблему в каком-то общем виде не выйдет, сама проблема находится в **PhysX**, то есть, будет актуальна для unity, unreal engine и прочих.

Есть несколько способов ухода от этой проблемы:

1. **Не использовать некинематический `Rigidbody` для персонажа.**

   Тут все просто, если чего-то нет, то с этим и нет проблем. Используем
   для своих персонажей `Character Controller`, либо делаем полностью
   все сами через `kinematic Rigidbody`. Есть только проблемы с
   фактически полной реализацией свой физики для персонажа, но из
   плюсов полный контроль.
2. **Попробовать скрыть, уменьшить случаи проблемного поведение**

   <s>*Можно переопределить `OnCollisionEnter` и при обнаружении
   незапланированного начала отскока возвращать `Rigidbody` на землю
   (костыль адовый, но кто-то использует).*</s>

   Простым вариантом является уменьшение `contactOffset` у проблемных
   коллайдеров и персонажа
   (`myGameObject.GetComponent<SomeCollider>().contactOffset`), либо
   уменьшение Default Contact Offset в настройках проекта (`Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics -> Default Contact Offset`)

   Стоит заметить, что при слишком низком значении, `Rigidbody` может
   начать трястись на ровной поверхность, поэтому с этим параметром
   придется экспериментировать, также это не защитит от отскоков от
   скрытых стен при частичных провалах внутрь коллайдера (при падении с
   высоты), поэтому придется это как-то дополнительно обрабатывать и
   исключать (`Raycast`, `SphereCast`).

   Даже при изменении `Contact Offset`, при обнаружении коллизий
   методом `continuous speculative` отскоки будут наблюдаться.
3. **Генерация общего коллайдер меша для дороги**

   Способ ресурсозатратный, необходимо собрать нужные коллайдеры
   участков дороги, удалить перекрывающиеся грани и склеить в один
   единственный меш коллайдер. Для кубов и плейнов работает хорошо, но
   все меняется на более сложных моделях. В местах множества узких
   полиговнов, даже если все эти полигоны лежат в одной плоскости,
   опять вылазят подскоки и дрожания. Поэтому придется для таких
   моделей отдельно избавляться от таких мест в меш коллайдерах, либо
   уменьшать `contactOffset` для всей конструкции и персонажа.

**Для большинства случаев наиболее верным решением будет использовать первый вариант.**